# Java ciclo do while

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int opc = 0;
do{
  ...
}while (opc != 6);
```

Me aparece este error, sé que aun me falta código pero no deberia marcarme el ciclo con error no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que se ve en la imagen, el problema es que esta FUERA de una función..

Pon algo así

```
void func() {
    int opc = 0;

    do{
      // ??? 
    } while (opc != 6);
}
```

Ademas, así como esta no hay forma que salga del loop, es posible que el inspector de código se de cuenta y te avise que la aplicación quedara bloqueada.

Agrega algo que permita la salida, ejemplo.

```
int opc = 0;

do{
  opc ++;
} while (opc != 6);
```

Comment: gracias estaba tan concentrado en la otra clase que no me percate que el do while quedaba fuera del metodo main, eso era el error. Gracias por ayudar. Buen día.

Comment: @AngeloCastro de nada, recuerda marcar la respuesta que te ayudo como correcta. Saludos.

Answer (score -2):

Haces un bucle do-while pero sin realizar nada? Que objetivo tendría.

```
do{
//???
}while(opc!=6);
```

Introduce la tarea a realizar y asegura exista la variable entera opc.

```
int opc = 0;
```

Revisa que el bloque de código este realmente dentro de un método, puede ser la razón por la cual el IDE marca un problema.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: si no tiene nada la duda es por que me marca error por lo general  yo hago el ciclo y pongo la condicion del while de una vez. Y en esta ocasión me lo marca con error. Obvio tenga o no mas código dentro del bucle me lo marca con ese error no puse el código porque lo que me interesa es el porque me marca el do while con error.

Comment: Asegura la variable opc exista y sea de tipo entera.

Comment: con ctrl+f1 encima de la linea de error, te muestra más información sobre el.

Comment: si lo único que hice fue meter el do while dentro del metodo main, ya que por error lo coloque fuera del método y por esta razón me marcaba como error, luego de eso escribí el código que necesitaba dentro del do while, para el que me pregunto que hice para resolverlo y gracias al que observo que el do while había quedado por fuera del método, jaja yo no me habia percatado de eso.